# Share an object with certain users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share objects on a FB users friends timeline where the user the post is shared with would be the only user able to see that object. Also that object should have the ability to be updated or the restrictions changed at a later date. I have read through the API docs but nothing has jumped out at me saying this is the API call that you call to do it. Does one exist? If so what is it, how should it be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific privacy parameter you can use for complete control over who sees a post. The [Privacy Parameter docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/) should contain all you need :)